# How can we access appsettings.json file values inside static class in .net core 6.0

Tags: static, config

I am converting my app from .net 4.5 to .net core 6.there inside static class we were able to get config values, but not getting idea about getting config values in static class

I was trying to use configuration builder but not getting extension methods like addjson file or setbasepath

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.